# How to send each player a list of players while excluding themselves from the list

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, socket.io

Sorry for the confusing title.

If I have an array as `['Peter','James','Susan','Thomas']` and I want to get the `array.length` number of new arrays (in this case is 4), with each of the new array having one less different name of the original one.

So what I want is this 4 arrays:

```
['James','Susan','Thomas']
['Peter','Susan','Thomas']
['Peter','James','Thomas']
['Peter','James','Susan']
```

And if I want to sent each new array to person whose name is not there. (So I want to sent Peter `['James','Susan','Thomas']`, and to James `['Peter','Susan','Thomas']`.

My current code is:

```
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    var player = array[i]
    var newArray= array.splice(i,1)
    io.to(player)emit('message', newArray)
}
```

The returned array only has one name in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `array.splice()` modifies the original array. You need to make a copy of it first, so you don't destroy the original. You also shouldn't assign `.splice` to `newArray`, because it returns an array of the elements that were removed, not the modified array.

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var player = array[i];
    var newArray = array.slice();
    newArray.splice(i, 1);
    io.to(player).emit('message', newArray);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array#splice` actually mutates the array it is called upon. The reason it can be confusing is that it also returns an array containing the elements you just deleted -- hence you receiving an array with a single item. Try using `Array#forEach` instead, and make a copy of your `array` using `Array#slice` before running `splice` so that the original array is not damaged with each iteration.

```js
// For demo purposes
var io = { to: function(player) { return { emit: function(s, msg) { console.log(player, 'received', msg) } } } }


var array = ['Peter', 'James', 'Susan', 'Thomas']

array.forEach(function(player, i, a) {
  (a = a.slice()).splice(i, 1)
  io.to(player).emit('message', a)
})
```